# Easier way to access mysql database tables?

Tags: mysql

In `postgresql` all you needed to do was type in `postgres <database_name>`
to access the database. In MySql, you need to do this:

```
mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 52
Server version: 5.7.20 Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use arthouse_development
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> select * from catalog_items;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from catalog_items
    -> ;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from users;
Empty set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from users
    -> ;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Is there a way to not have to specify the user name and specify the database all in one line?

How do you see all the tables in mysql once inside the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers mention the `--database` / `-D` option, but you don't even need that.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html shows the simpler example:

> Using mysql is very easy. Invoke it from the prompt of your command
>   interpreter as follows:
>
> ```
> shell> mysql db_name
> ```

In other words, *exactly like the usage you showed for `postgres <database_name>`*.

You may also need to supply username and password to authenticate for the MySQL instance, but I prefer to put those into an option file so I don't have to type them repeatedly.

```
$ cat ~/.my.cnf

[client]
username = scott
password = tiger
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html for more on these files.

There's also an optional way to store the user credentials encrypted. For this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html

Any software is easier to use if you try reading a little bit of the documentation! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use the -D option of the program mysql the default login with a database.
 
The -p option let's you enter a password into the mysql program

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysql -u root -p -D stackoverflow
Enter password: **
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 10
Server version: 5.7.20-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

Confirm we are using the database stackoverflow.

```
mysql> select database();
+---------------+
| database()    |
+---------------+
| stackoverflow |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

> How do you see all the tables in mysql once inside the database?

```
mysql> show tables;
+-------------------------+
| Tables_in_stackoverflow |
+-------------------------+
| baskets                 |
| baskets_fruits          |
| conditions              |
| employee                |
| employees               |
| hugetable               |
| kanji                   |
| newtable                |
| result                  |
| t1                      |
| t2                      |
| table1                  |
| table_test              |
| temp                    |
| test                    |
| testing                 |
| word                    |
+-------------------------+
17 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or by using information_schema.TABLES table

```
mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'stackoverflow';
+----------------+
| TABLE_NAME     |
+----------------+
| baskets        |
| baskets_fruits |
| conditions     |
| employee       |
| employees      |
| hugetable      |
| kanji          |
| newtable       |
| result         |
| t1             |
| t2             |
| table1         |
| table_test     |
| temp           |
| test           |
| testing        |
| word           |
+----------------+
17 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You can also create [personal option files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) with defaults like this.

Answer (score 1):

Using `man mysql` to view the mysql manpage you'll find the `-D` flag:

> ```
>    ·   --database=db_name, -D db_name
>
>        The database to use. This is useful primarily in an option file.
> ```